# How do I make tastypie accept a JSONField?

Tags: django, json, field, tastypie, bad-request

I'm getting a "BAD REQUEST: '' is not a valid JSON string." when I try to post data to my tastypie API. The API consist of a ModelResource which is based on a model having a [JSONField](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield). The JSONfield is inheriting from the standard TextField django field.

If change the JSONField to a TextField, the data is received and all is well.

My code is similar to this:

model.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   data = jsonfield.JSONField() # If i change this to a TextField everything works
   ...
```

api.py

```
class MyModel(ModelResource):
    #Resource for MyModel()
    ...
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
```

Inspired by [this](https://github.com/newsapps/django-boundaryservice/blob/master/boundaryservice/tastyhacks.py), I've tried overriding the default ModelResource, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

So to sum up, how do I make tastypie accept the JSONField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally figured out the problem.

When django recieves the request, it causes the creation of an initial empty MyModel object. And as my models JSONField does not have a default value, it uses the super class' default value which is an empty string "". When the JSONField is initiated the empty string "" it raises an exception saying that "'' is not a valid JSON string.". This further triggers the 400 BAD REQUEST response.

I think this is a bug in the JSONField package, it should have *None* as a default value.

An easy fix for this problem however is to just change the model like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   data = jsonfield.JSONField(default=None)
   ...
```

Comment: According to this guy `null` or `blank` works as well. He also suggests overriding JSONField's index method: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/iS5aE3R5JP4